# Cakephp error messages might be my .htaccess file

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to get this cakephp project running on my localhost, but always receiving a couple of error messages

***I receive this error message:***

Warning: include(Cake\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\cts\app\webroot\index.php on line 77

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Cake\bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\cts\lib;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\cts\app\webroot\index.php on line 77

Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors root directory. in C:\wamp\www\cts\app\webroot\index.php on line 86

***end***

***code****
Index.php file:

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
    }
    /**line 77**/
    if (!include('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
} else {
    if (!include(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
}

if (!empty($failed)) {
    /**line 86**/
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

***end of file***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check line 59 of index.php you will see something like

```
//define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
```

Uncomment that line and if it does not work, then hardcode the complete path to your lib/ folder, the one containing a Cake folder with all CakePHP libraries.

Comment: New error message after I uncommented: Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\cts\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\cts\app\webroot\index.php on line 81

Comment: complete path to your lib/ folder gave me a 500 internal error message

Comment: As I told you, if that fails try hardcoding the value of that constant to the correct path where your Cake folder is

Comment: @Dale if that is an apache error, then check the logs. That might be a problem with htaccess or just a php error because of a badly configured server.

Comment: //define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib'); change that to: define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '/full/path');

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14800/discussion-between-dale-and-jose-lorenzo)

Comment: Hey Dale, How you resolved above issue ? as i am getting same issue.
Please assist me. I did the same thing as mentioned but no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying a CakePHP project from one directory to another, make sure you copy all required directories.

When copying my project from an old directory to a new directory, and I mistakenly omitted CakePHP's `/lib` directory thinking it contained unnecessary git or log files.

I was incorrect, and copying over the `/lib` directory to the new project directory resolved the fatal error for me.